# Recursive LinkedList. Which implementation is better and why?

Tags: python, linked-list, comparative-review

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LinkedList:

  def __init__(self):
      self.head = None
```

> ```
> def insert(self, data):
>     self.head = self.insertHelper(self.head, data)
>
> def insertHelper(self, head, data):
>     if(head == None):
>         return Node(data)
>     else:
>         head.next = self.insertHelper(head.next, data)
>     return head
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> def insertR(self, data):
>     self.insertRHelper(self.head, data)
>
> def insertRHelper(self, head, data):
>         if(head == None):
>             self.head = Node(data)
>         elif(head.next == None):
>             head.next = Node(data)
>         else:
>             self.insertRHelper(head.next, data)
> ```

Any reason why one of these implementations would be better? Personally think the insertR version is easier to look at.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Did you write both?

Comment: insertR() is purely mine. insert() was inspired by geeksforgeeks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both of these implementations are bad.

The first is probably worse.

- every node in the linked list, from `self.head` to the last node's `head.next` is unconditionally written to, which makes every cache-line/cache-page/virtual-memory-page the linked list touches "dirty" and need to be flushed/written.
- `self.head` is passed to `insertHelper()`, which recursively calls itself N times, eventually (assuming N > 1) returning the value that it was given `self.head`, to be stored back into the `self.head` member.  This is a LONG critical section.  If any threading support was added, locks would need to be held way longer than necessary.

## Recursion

Both use recursion, and Python [does not do tail-call-optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13592002/3690024).  This means that if your linked-list is very long, you will get a stack overflow.  There are [manual ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506625/3690024) to make your function behave in a tail-call-optimized fashion, even if Python won't do it for you, but they are complex and it is by far simpler to just use a loop.

## PEP-8

- Both `insertHelper` and `insertRHelper` are helper functions, which should not be exposed a public methods.  They should begin with a leading underscore to indicate they are not part of the public interface.
- The members `next`, `head`, and probably `data` should also not be public, so should be named with a leading underscore.
- Classes are named using `BumpyWords`; functions, members and variables should all be `snake_case`.  These means `insertHelper` should be named `_insert_helper`, and so on.
- `if(...):` is not Pythonic.  The parenthesis are unnecessary.

## Tail

The best solution would be to maintain a `._tail` member in the `LinkedList`:

```
class LinkedList:
    """Description of class here"""

    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None
        self._tail = None

    def insert(self, data: Node) -> None:
        """Description of the insert function here"""

        if self._tail:
            self._tail._next = Node(data)
            self._tail = self._tail._next
        else:
            self._head = self._tail = Node(data)
```

Now, insertions at the tail of the `LinkedList` are \$O(1)\$.

## Naming

As mentioned by [Matthieu M.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/8999/matthieu-m) in the comments:

> I would also consider *renaming* here: `insert` should be `append`, to make it clear where the insert occurs, and offer a path to proposing different insertions such as `prepend`, or `insert` with an index.

Comment: I think you forgot to update `self._tail` in the case where it already exists.

Comment: @ovs Good catch.  Fixed.

Comment: I would also consider _renaming_ here: `insert` should be `append`, to make it clear where the insert occur, and offer a path to proposing different insertions such as `prepend`, or `insert` with an index.

Comment: @AJNeufeld: I'd honestly prefer if you added it to your answer. I find reading a bunch of short disconnected answer less interesting as the ordering by vote is just not as good as one well-structured answer.

Comment: Not that I think you’re wrong, but sources or data to back the claim on cache lines would be useful here. There’s enough layers between python code and cpu execution that knowing that off-hand is, well, dubious